# ObjectBox Generator: Error: No named parameter with the name 'lazy'

Tags: flutter, dart, objectbox, flutter-objectbox

I registered my ObjectBox Store as a LazySingleton with this method

```
setupLocatorAdditions() async {
  stackedAdditionLocator.registerLazySingletonAsync<Store>(() => openStore());
}
```

Which worked fine. But after multiple rebuilds from the BuildRunner the ObjectBox Generator threw this error, regardless of whether I removed the singleton registration and reran it.

```
lib/objectbox.g.dart:1341:67: Error: No named parameter with the name 'lazy'.
              weekDays: const fb.ListReader<int>(fb.Int8Reader(), lazy: false)
                                                                  ^^^^
../../Flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/objectbox-1.1.1/lib/flatbuffers/flat_buffers.dart:994:9: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
  const ListReader(this._elementReader);
        ^^^^^^^^^^

lib/objectbox.g.dart:1343:68: Error: No named parameter with the name 'lazy'.
              locations: const fb.ListReader<int>(fb.Int8Reader(), lazy: false)
                                                                   ^^^^
../../Flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/objectbox-1.1.1/lib/flatbuffers/flat_buffers.dart:994:9: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.

  const ListReader(this._elementReader);
        ^^^^^^^^^^
2

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That argument isn't part of the released objectbox-dart v1.1.1 (it was added by [this commit](https://github.com/objectbox/objectbox-dart/commit/999ad4d25d3582e33afd464d8b3ec2f1fe6f2f99) 13 days ago while v1.1.1 was released 19 days ago).

Looks like you're using a mismatching generator? Can you check your `pubspec.yaml` if you're using a dependency override on objectbox_generator, e.g. from git? If you're using a dependency override you should stick to a specific commit and make sure you use it on both generator and objectbox library itself. If you don't need the dependency override, just remove it from your `pubspec.yaml`.

In both cases, run `pub get` after making the changes and `pub run build_runner build`.

Comment: yeah I just used the dependency override for the generator you suggest in my last thread, but didn't override objectbox package. I now referenced the same commit for this package and it worked like it should. Thank you once more